# C# Save Values in the Database with a primary key

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

```
CineStarEntities entities = new CineStarEntities();
Address address = new Address();
entities.Address.Add(address);
address.AccountID = (int)accountIDNumericUpDown.Value;
address.Street = streetTextBox.Text;
address.PostCode = postCodeTextBox.Text;
address.Place = placeTextBox.Text;
address.FirstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
address.SecondName = secondNameTextBox.Text;
entities.SaveChanges();
```

My primary Key is also in a NumericUpDown(`addressIDNumericUpDown`) and now I want to save these values in the database with the primary key? But the primary does already exist in the database. So what can I do?(I want to do a update function)

Comment: You can't do anything. you should change the primary key, its can't be `Duplicated`. Otherwise whats the purpose of `Primary Key`

Comment: Why don't you use an auto increment field for PK?

Comment: If you want to update then why don't you use SQL Update query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the entity to the `DbSet`, attach the entity as modified:

```
entities.Entry( address ).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key already present in the database then you cannot insert the new data into your database. Primary key is unique and it cannot be duplicated. You can remove the entry explicitly and then try again.